# how to search textbox in dapper with database MS-Access in VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, dapper

How to read Select in dapper with database MS-Access in VB.NET? I tried doing a search in the textbox but it didn't work what was wrong with my code.

```
Private Sub FillDataGridView()
    Dim param As New DynamicParameters()
    param.Add("SELECT * FROM Contact WHERE @Nme='' OR Nme LIKE '%'+@Nme+'%'", txtSearch.Text.Trim())
    Dim list As List(Of Contact) = oledbCon.Query(Of Contact)("Select ContactID,Nme,Mobile,Address from contact", param, commandType:=CommandType.Text).ToList()

    dgvContact.DataSource = list

    dgvContact.Columns(0).Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    If Not Me.btnSearch.IsHandleCreated Then Return
    Try
        FillDataGridView()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used dapper before, but literally the first example in their GitHub readme shows how to execute a query and map the results to a strongly typed List ([here](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper#execute-a-query-and-map-the-results-to-a-strongly-typed-list)).

It would look something along these lines:

```vb
Dim contacts = oledbCon.Query(Of Contact)("SELECT ContactID, Nme, Mobile, Address FROM contact WHERE Nme='' OR Nme LIKE @NmeLike", New With {
    .NmeLike = $"%{txtSearch.Text.Trim()}%"
}).ToList()
```

Comment: thanks for the reply from you. I put your code in the btnSearch button but it hasn't worked yet. I'm using visual studio 2012 so my code is rendered like this `String.Concat("%{txtSearch.Text.Trim()}%")`

Comment: If you cannot use String interpolation, use String.Format instead: `String.Format("%{0}%", txtSearch.Text.Trim())`

Comment: thanks reply from you but I tried the code when I clicked the search button did not run at all

Comment: I don't know what to tell you other than you need to start leveraging the debugging tools.

Comment: I place the your answer code in the search event button "btnSearch" whether it is correct

Comment: sorry I replied late